# Is Google+ available for Google Apps accounts?

Tags: google-workspace, google-plus

[Google Plus](http://plus.google.com) launched today but when I try to check it out, I get the error:

> Google Profiles is not available for your organization.

I have Google Apps on my domain. Am I missing a setting in my administration panel where I enable this feature or is it simply not available to people with Google Apps yet?

My guess is the latter but I would just be surprised if Google launched with it disabled for Google Apps users.

Answer (score 25):

Google+ (and the +1 button) require a Google Profile, and Google hasn't activated Profiles for Apps users yet.

Google [stated back in March](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2011/03/coming-soon-to-google-apps-1-button-and.html) that Profiles were "coming soon" for Apps, but there's still no sign of it.

---

UPDATE (July 21)

Still no sign of Profiles/Plus for Apps users, but Googlers keep saying it's coming ["in the coming months"](http://wellsb.com/post/7022247022/google-plus-for-google-apps-in-the-coming-months).

John Costigan, Technical Lead for Google Profiles:

> "We're actively working on making Profiles (and Google+) available for
>   Google Apps - it should be available in the coming months." ([June
>   28](https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!msg/google-plus-discuss/o9Tn_H85gkg/ShaSO_tXhHcJ))

Dave Girouard, President of Enterprise at Google:

> "Making Google+ work for Google Apps users is a very high priority for
>   the team. Sorry to make you wait - we have to do it right." ([June
>   29](https://twitter.com/#!/davegirouard/status/86130257597435904))

Answer (score 12):

Google [has announced that as of 27 October 2011](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2011/10/google-is-now-available-with-google.html) Google+ is working with google apps accounts.

> **Enabling Google+ for Google Apps**
>
> We recommend you follow these steps to roll out Google+ to your users:
>
> - [**Review the list of considerations for enabling Google+**](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=1689647)
>
>   It's important to understand how Google+ works, what your users can
>     do, and what they can share outside your organization before you
>     enable the service.
> - [**Review system requirements for Hangouts**](http://www.google.com/support/plus/bin/answer.py?answer=1216376)
>
>   Make sure users' computers meet the browser, operating system, and
>     other requirements for Hangouts and Hangouts with extras.
> - [**Check firewall settings for Hangouts**](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=1279090)
>
>   You might need to adjust your firewall settings for Hangouts and Hangouts with extras to work.
> - [**Enable Google+**](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=1631746)
>
>   You can enable the service for your entire organization or just
>     specific users. Consider enabling Google+ for a small group of users
>     first as a trial, and then enable the service for the rest of your
>     organization.
> - [**Tell your users about their new service**](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?&answer=1631747)
>
>   Make sure you let your users know that Google+ is available for
>     their Google Apps accounts and how they can sign up.
>
> [Taken from this Google Help Article](http://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=1631744)

Answer (score 7):

Google Plus is now allowed for Google Apps users. The administrator for your domain has to enable the service first, and then it takes a few hours for it to be enabled for the individual users.

> To turn on support, an administrator needs to login to the Google Apps
>   dashboard.
>
> [image]
>
> Once logged in, go to the “Organization & users” section and click on
>   the “Services” tab. Scroll down until you see “Google+” and then you
>   can toggle the service on or off.
>
> Administrators can enable Google+ for all users in an organization or
>   for select users. Once access is enabled, users need to sign up at the
>   regular Google+ page.

Source: [Google+ Comes to Google Apps](http://mashable.com/2011/10/27/google-plus-google-apps-2/)

Comment: FYI, it worked for my Google Apps account: https://plus.google.com/u/0/100092285244313548023